# Reduce size of a presigned url

Tags: image, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, pre-signed-url

Displaying a list containing pre-signed urls of images. It takes time to load the images. Is there a way to reduce the size of the image or a way to load the images faster.

Tried converting the image to a canvas to reduce the size of the image. But still takes longer for the image to load

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Image optimization is a broad topic, you can maybe start here:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/11/guide-image-optimization-jamstack-sites/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/printed-books/image-optimization/
- https://web.dev/fast/#optimize-your-images

Mainly, shipping the proper size + format will get you a long way. Lazy loading + other tricks/optimizations can be applied.

Hard to say more without more effort/context from your side.